# How to change icon marker with angularjs and google maps

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, cordova, phonegap-plugins

im working in phonegap project with angularjs google maps (https://github.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps)
I need to change default icon marker with custom images.
This is my controller code:

core.js

```
// Map Markers Controller

app.controller('markersController', function($scope, $compile){

$scope.infoWindow = {
    title: 'title',
    content: 'content'
};

$scope.markers = [
    {
        'title' : 'Location #1',
        'content' : 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing     elit. Cras a viverra magna',
        'location'  : [40.7112, -74.213]
    }, 
    {
        'title' : 'Location #2',
        'content' : 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras a viverra magna',
        'location'  : [40.7243, -74.2014]
    }, 
    {
        'title' : 'Location #3',
        'content' : 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras a viverra magna',
        'location'  : [40.7312, -74.1923]
    }
];

$scope.showMarker = function(event){

    $scope.marker = $scope.markers[this.id];
    $scope.infoWindow = {
        title: $scope.marker.title,
        content: $scope.marker.content
    };
    $scope.$apply();
    $scope.showInfoWindow(event, 'marker-info', this.getPosition());
 }
});
```

And this is my markers.html

```
<div ng-controller="markersController" class="map-fullscreen-container">
<map zoom="8" center="[-26.82, -54.84]" class="fullscreen">

  <info-window id="marker-info">
    <div ng-non-bindable="">
      <strong class="markerTitle">{{ infoWindow.title }}</strong>
      <div class="markerContent">
        <p>{{ infoWindow.content }}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </info-window>

  <marker ng-repeat="(id, marker) in markers" id="{{ id }}" 
  position="{{marker.location}}" 
  on-click="showMarker(event, $index)" >
  </marker>

 </map>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you only have one marker, you can set it up directly on your `marker` directive:

```
<marker ng-repeat="(id, marker) in markers" id="{{ id }}" 
            position="{{marker.location}}" 
            on-click="showMarker(event, $index)"
            icon="yourIconUrl.png" >
</marker>
```

If you have different markers for each item, the first thing you need to do is to add the `icon` property to your items:

```
$scope.markers = [
    {
        'title' : 'Location #1',
        'content' : 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras a viverra magna',
        'location'  : [40.7112, -74.213],
        'icon' : 'yourIconUrl.png'
    }, 
    {
        'title' : 'Location #2',
        'content' : 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras a viverra magna',
        'location'  : [40.7243, -74.2014],
        'icon' : 'yourIconUrl.png'
    }, 
    {
        'title' : 'Location #3',
        'content' : 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras a viverra magna',
        'location'  : [40.7312, -74.1923],
        'icon' : 'yourIconUrl.png'
    }
];
```

Then you need to use it on your html, by adding it to the `marker` directive:

```
<marker ng-repeat="(id, marker) in markers" id="{{ id }}" 
        position="{{marker.location}}" 
        on-click="showMarker(event, $index)"
        icon="{{marker.icon}}" >
</marker>
```

That's it, hope that helps.

Please refer to the documentation for more info:
https://rawgit.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps/master/build/docs/index.html

Comment: Thanks fedaykin but have an error, look my site http://recorramisiones.com.ar/rutadelaselva/app/

Comment: Dont worry, i forget "," :) I cant vote you yet bu thanks a lot. Greetings from Argentina

Comment: Sorry, me again... how rezise the icon? css?

Comment: to resize the icon, you must simply resize the image, you can mark this as an answer, can't you?

Comment: Are there default icons we can choose from? Like the default seems to be the red upside down drop. Are there preloaded default ones like perhaps a green upside down drop/ blue etc.?