# Add custom marker icon to angular-google-maps when markers are from external JSON

Tags: angularjs, icons, markers, angular-google-maps

I'm new to Angular (so probably am making some silly mistakes) and I'm trying to add some markers to a map instance with a custom image icon.

I understand that the best way to do this is to add this into the items as [suggested by Fedaykin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28308997/how-to-change-icon-marker-with-angularjs-and-google-maps) but is there a way to do this if you can't change the JSON file?

I was able to add the custom icon for a single marker, so I wondered if I could do the same for several markers using 'forEach', but although this shows all my markers it doesn't add the icon.

```
$scope.marker = Mapdata.query(function() {  

    var image = "https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/info-i_maps.png";

    $scope.$watch('data', function(data) {
        angular.forEach($scope.marker, function(markerList, id, coords, icon) {
            $scope.markerList = [{

                id: data.id,
                coords: {
                    latitude: data.latitude,
                    longitude: data.longitude
                },

                icon: image

            }];
        });
    });

});
```

The html is just the usual angular-google-maps stuff

```
 <ui-gmap-google-map center="map.center" zoom="map.zoom" draggable="true">
  <ui-gmap-markers models="marker.boards" coords="'self'" fit="'true'" icon="markerList.icon" click="'onClick'"></ui-gmap-markers>
</ui-gmap-google-map>
```

I have a [plunker here](http://plnkr.co/edit/xcsTYjkFicgUQiUkbAte?p=preview) to put it all in context.

Thanks for any help or advice :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Made a few changes:

**index.html**

- `icon="markerList.icon"` --> `icon="'icon'"`

**script.js**

I didn't quite understand what you  were trying to to with the $watch - I ended up just setting the image attribute of each marker when the data is initially fetched.

- `Mapdata.query(function() {` --> `Mapdata.query(function(data) {`
- `$scope.$watch` thing -->

  ```
  angular.forEach(data.boards, function(board) {
      board.icon = image;
  });
  ```

[Here's the updated plunker.](http://plnkr.co/edit/unvb4n2RQ0zG7l5FN5Xn?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you Fissio, that's perfect. I really appreciate your help :)